# Adding facebook/twitter login option to website users

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, twitter, authentication

Users details are held in database table called user where I have fields username and password among others. Now, I need to give users additional option to login using facebook and twitter.
I know how to handle these authentications but what I can't think is -

How to identify which FB user account relates to which local user account? How do I do this?

I'm not looking for code but the process. The process in my mind is somewhat as below -
User logs in using username and password of my website. then they can add FB or Twitter as external authentication and when they do it I ask them to login to FB. On successful FB login I save some unique fb id (i don't know which as haven't checked yet) in the users table. Next time they can just login using FB as I'd be able to identify which local record they belong to. Is this how you would do this?

What would you suggest?  Thanks for your inputs in advance.

PS - I'll be adding multiple networks (like linkedin and others) but at the moment fb and twitter only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is :
@Registration

```
1. Allow the user to register with Facebook, Twitter
2. Once the process has completed, redirect the user to create a username on your site
3. Using the email obtained from Facebook, Twitter, and username from local form, insert all this information into a db table.
4. This will allow referencing between FB, TW, and local usernames
```

Comment: Hmm - but what about existing users? There are admin people who create user accounts too (then system send them login details by email).

Comment: Hmm - for existing users, you can write a small script to reference the email addresses in you db vs. the ones from facebook. If they are the same, update the table with thef acebook creds. For manual submissions, I would assume it could work the same way, but I do not know the setup you have.

Comment: @mlishn: You just posted this when i am typing the same thing..
any how +1 to you...

Comment: so basically 2-step process as what I have already thought about ... need to think if theres better way - thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

create a interrelated table which will hold userid, facebook or twitter userid, authentication type (facebook or twitter).

Comment: How/when do I populate this table? (with which username to which social network id?)

Comment: look, when a user logedin using facebook or twitter in your site , u will get the user's facebook uderid nd twitter userid as facebook and twitter both returns the userid . Keep all necessary data into user table and socoial login data in another table. (Atfirst u have to register user in your site, then u will get the last inserted user id. Against this id u will keep data in new table)

Comment: And for the existing user u have to matchup against id,not email. Coz twitter doesn't return user email.